# sunspot how query specific field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Reading through Sunspot documentation I am trying to find how I can query **autocomplete fields**.

**I create them like here** https://github.com/haitham/sunspot_autocomplete

Here is config solr/conf/schema.xml

```
<types>
  .......
  <fieldType name="autocomplete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LetterTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="autosuggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LetterTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  .....
</types>
<fields>
  ....
  <dynamicField name="*_ac" type="autocomplete" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_as" type="autosuggest" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
  ....
</fields>
```

I have model with searchable fields:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :user_id

  has_one :user

  searchable do
    text :text
    integer :user_id, :references => User
    autocomplete :post_text, :using => :text
  end
end
```

When I try to search against an autocomplete field like so:

```
Sunspot.search(Post) { keywords('ra', :fields => :'autocomplete') }
```

I get the error:

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError: No text field configured for Post with name 'autocomplete'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**I shared the application on github: https://github.com/pironim/my_sunspot_app.git**

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir,

You're using the documentation for the plugin, but it doesn't appear you are actually using the plugin. You don't need to use the plugin, you can define a custom field, and tell Sunspot to use it.

Your configuration in `schema.xml` looks fine. In your `searchable` block, I would do the following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :user_id

  has_one :user

  searchable do
    text :text, :stored => true, :as => :text_ac
    integer :user_id, :references => User
  end
end
```

Once you make this change, be sure to `rake sunspot:solr:stop` => `rake sunspot:solr:start` => `rake sunspot:solr:reindex` so Sunspot and Solr know of the usage of the dynamic field.

Then when searching, do the following:

```
Sunspot.search(Post) { 
  keywords('ra') 
}
```

Comment: Plugin add support *_ac and *_as types without it fields do not indexing well(I can grab one file which do thats and delete plugin). But can I define text :text; text :text, :as => :text_ac - to left my regular search as is and autocomplete - search *_ac fields? How can I add *_ac fields to **searchable** block without influens on regular search which already defined and working

Comment: I'm looking for query to make autocomplete. And get results like ['ra', 'rai', 'rail', 'rails']

Comment: I've edited my original answer -- See how I've added the `:autocomplete_text` attribute? it still uses the same field, but indexed in a different way.

Comment: Your solution allow make search even with one word but it affect even regular queries like **Post.search { keywords 's' }.result** I want create functionality which does not change regular search. It's only for autocomplete .